# Help on reconciling seemingly contradictory evidence about fetal experience

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience

Fetal awareness and especially fetal pain are controversial, political issues. However, I do not wish to get into politics and want to merely stick to the scientific evidence. I have found statements about fetuses in the womb that seem to contradict each other, yet there has been no reference to the opponents in either side.

Some believe that fetuses do not have awareness in the womb and cannot feel pain. [Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1440624/) is an argument along those lines, claiming that fetuses cannot feel pain, even when their nervous systems and brain are developed, because the chemical environment within the womb suppresses awareness and experience that shapes the brain only happens outside the womb.

However, some other evidence seems to claim that fetuses can have experience. Twins can interact with each other in the womb as early as 14 weeks of gestation, as stated [here](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/social-before-birth/). It is possible to learn in the womb, and newborns, even after they are born, can retain this knowledge, as stated [here](https://www.parenting.com/article/what-babies-learn-in-the-womb).

I'm not sure what to think. Are some of these statements, such as the idea fetuses are not aware, just incorrect? Or can interaction and learning occur without awareness somehow? (I know pain is distinct from awareness, interaction, and learning. What seemed particularly strange was the idea that fetuses have no conscious experience whatsoever, especially as no one making that claim, as far as I know, even mentioned the evidence about interaction and learning at all).

Comment: FYI, your third link gives a 404 response.

Comment: @vkehayas It doesn't for me, so I'm not sure what happened to you. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I know close to nothing about the subject of self-awareness in fetuses.

But learning —and certainly interaction— can occur without anything close to human "awareness", as evident by the fact that systems without a brain (and even without neurons) can learn. Any system that can process and store information is capable of learning. Does your definition of awareness include anything more than this? Conversely, organisms with a very simple brain can display aversive behaviour.

For an example of memory without neurons, see the Wikipedia article on [immunological memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immunological_memory).
For examples of aversive behaviour without a proper brain see [Zhang, Lu, and Bargmann 2005](http://www.lulab.gatech.edu/wp-content/uploads/2007/07/nature042161.pdf) and [Babin et al. 2014](http://rsbl.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/roybiolett/10/3/20140048.full.pdf)

<sub>**References**

Zhang, Y., Lu, H., & Bargmann, C. I. (2005). Pathogenic bacteria induce aversive olfactory learning in Caenorhabditis elegans. *Nature*, **438**(7065), 179–184.

Babin, A., Kolly, S., Schneider, F., Dolivo, V., Zini, M., & Kawecki, T. J. (2014). Fruit flies learn to avoid odours associated with virulent infection. *Biology Letters*, **10**(3), 20140048–20140048.</sub>

Comment: Um, don't fruit flies and C. elegans have an actual brain? Yes, I know it would be a very small brain, but it still counts as a brain, as far as I know. Anyway, stuff such as invertebrate awareness is controversial as well, to say the least, but I don't believe there has been 100% proof that they *aren't* conscious, and some scientists believe it exists.

Comment: Furthermore, I was actually talking about the point when the nervous system and brain do develop in fetuses. The argument I mentioned was *not* about whether those things had developed (they have by that time), but whether the *chemical* environment in the womb suppressed consciousness. The studies you mentioned don't seem to be relevant anyway, come to think of it.

Comment: @Inflationary_Bubble You asked if learning is possible without awareness. If you accept that the immune system does not have awareness, then I demonstrated one way learning is possible without human-like awareness. If you are willing to consider that the immune system and *C. elegans* have some rudimentary form of awareness, the only consistent thesis is [panpsychism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panpsychism).

Comment: @Inflationary_Bubble Then it becomes a matter of identifying the degree of awareness which is an empirical question that is not really possible to answer with current methods, although it is reasonable to assume that the maturity of the fetal nervous system could be a relevant parameter. But please note that in that case the apparent contradiction also dissolves, as awareness is no longer a binary feature. The definition issue of whether you call it a brain or a collection of ganglia in the case of *C. elegans* is inconsequential for the answer.

Comment: @Inflationary_Bubble The fundamental problem in the apparent contradiction is then that you consider awareness as a binary feature (you either have it or you don't). However there exists no clear line dividing aware from non-aware systems. In my opinion, it is more productive to think in terms of information processing and storing.

Comment: @vkehayas - I think that your answer would benefit by including the points raised in the comments above.

Comment: @LinuxBlanket Agreed, will try to do if I find the time. Feel free to do so yourself if you'd like.